# sanitize using {$_GET['id']} doesn't display mysql info

Tags: php, mysql, sanitization

I am trying to sanitize my $_GET input but for some reason, mysql doesn't retrieve the data from the DB. If I do this:

```
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['id']);

//execute query to call user info
$query = "SELECT user
FROM company
WHERE user={$_GET['id']} ";
```

this will work and the results are displayed; however if I do this:

```
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['id']);

//execute query to call user info
$query = "SELECT user
FROM company
WHERE user= '$user' ";
```

I don't get a database error, but nothing shows up.

Am I not sanitizing right? What's going on here? HELP, please!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Debug! `var_dump` all relevant values! Read the error messages! Tell us both!

Comment: In the second query you use some additional apostrophe (') around $user. They are missing around {$_GET['id']}.

Comment: In the second example are you assigning $_GET['id'] to the variable $user?

Comment: var_dump gives me: string(72) "SELECT user FROM user WHERE user='\"user\"' "

Answer (score 0):

Best way to avoid such situations is using prepared queries:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

It's very simple and effective:

```
$q = $db->prepare('SELECT user FROM company WHERE user=?');
$q->bind_param('i', $user);

$q->execute();

$result = $q->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

It's cool because it's OOP and it's safe. Some links:

- [Connection to DB](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)
- [Prepare statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [Bind parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: hi Spec, I appreciate your help. I am new to PHP not am that familiar with prepared statement, so the links helped a lot. I am getting this error when iterating your sample: fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: Where you connect to DB use this: `$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`. Of course fill those placeholders with your username, password and database name. I think you have to fully rebuild your connection with DB. Check "Connection to DB" for more details.